# Automatically Clear textbox when loaded VB

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I want my text boxes in my VB program to automatically clear when the program is loaded, I have already done this my but I was wondering if there is a short hand method just to keep the code reasonably tidy and reduce time spent wasted and unneeded repetition. I have added a small snippet of how they are currently.

```
Postcode.Text = ""
Address.Text = ""
HouseNumber.Text = ""
```

etc...

Comment: Why is this necessary at all? Shouldn’t they be clear at program startup?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop and set the value;

```
For Each tb In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
    tb.Text = ""
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

When you application loads, the textboxes should be empty, unless you are setting a default value.

Why do you think they would have entries?

You could use code such as:

```
For Each txt In {txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4}
  txt.Clear()
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, it only because I have a database linked to these text boxes and when the program is load it would some times populate them with information before the user has even started.

Comment: If this is bound to a database, would clearing the fields, not clear the entries in the database?

Answer (score 0):

As Karl has mentioned, your TexBoxes should already be empty; unless you're not unloading the form correctly when you close it?

To properly unload the form and remove any existing values within the form, you can just include `Unload Me` within the UserForm module, or `Unload Userform1` within a normal module.

For reference, you can loop through and clear each TextBox like below.

```
Dim ufControl As Control

For Each ufControl In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeName(ufControl) = "TextBox" Then
        ufControl.Text = ""
    End If
Next ufControl
```

Edit: Just realised you're not talking about Excel UserForms, however the principal should be pretty much the same.. loop through each TextBox and clear any values.